# embedding youtube iframe in ngb-carousel

Tags: html, angular, iframe, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to embed an Iframe into a ngb-carousel. the carousel is showing up fine, the iframe "tab" is not:

```
        <ngb-carousel *ngIf="project.images">
          <ng-template class="item" ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of project.images">
            <img class="img-fluid" [src]="image" alt="">
          </ng-template>

          <ng-template class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="project.video"></iframe>
          </ng-template>
        </ngb-carousel>
```

**edit**

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcmhun

Comment: What is your iframe tab showing ?

Comment: it's not showing a tab, say I have 2 image tabs and the video tab, its just showing the 2 image tabs

Comment: Hi! Just tried it out, seems to work fine, you need to update your question with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `ngbSlide` directive from the second `ng-template` in your example above. I edited your stackblitz example, adding that directive to the third `ng-template` in that example, and the embedded video shows up on a third tab as expected.

Forked example showing the solution: https://angular-ztaxde.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

yes please add ngbSlide:

```
        <ngb-carousel>
            <ng-template ngbSlide>
              <iframe width="500" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J2qDRJdTGow" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </ng-template>
          </ngb-carousel>
```